# I want to read data from excel file with multiple sheets which is greater than 10 mb

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, out-of-memory

My code works fine with smaller excel file But it wont work with large excel file it gives error OutOfMemory.

```
public void onReadClick (View view) {
    printlnToUser("reading XLSX file from resources");
    InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test3);
    try {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowsCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        for (int r = 0; r<10; r++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
            int cellsCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            for (int c = 0; c<cellsCount; c++) {
                String value = getCellAsString(row, c, formulaEvaluator);
                String cellInfo = "r:"+r+"; c:"+c+"; v:"+value;
                printlnToUser(cellInfo);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* proper exception handling to be here */
        printlnToUser(e.toString());
    }
}
```

> it leades to the following run time  error. please help soon.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. this is annoying remove this.

```
2019-06-06 03:30:43.535 5224-5224/pro.kondratev.xlsxpoiexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pro.kondratev.xlsxpoiexample, PID: 5224
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4707)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4702)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802) 
 Caused by:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

Comment: You seem to have a conversation going on in your ?, but haven't explained it.  Have you posted this before?  Is it a dupe?

Comment: My excel work book has multiple sheet

Comment: That doesn't address any of my questions.

Comment: no, I haven't posted it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give SXSSFWorkbook a shot. Instead of XSSFWorkbook (which keeps the entire Excel workbook in memory) try to use very efficient and high performance streaming SXSSFWorkbook class like below:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
```

where 100 is the default number of rows that will be kept in memory and processed in real time and other processed rows will be flushed.

Answer (score 0):

You get an out-of-memory error because POI reads, parses, and creates a whole data structure for your entire Excel file in memory. This can take a large amount of memory. I see that your program reads from a single worksheet. This tells me that you could export that worksheet to a .csv (comma-separated value) file. It would then be easy to read the data.

I do not know enough about your business process to see where the export to .csv could be done, or if that is even possible in your process. POI is notorious for using large amount of memory.

Another solution would be to read directly from the Excel file. The .xlsx file is actually a zip. You could open it and read your data from there. You would have to look at the [SpreadsheetML](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php) documentation to understand the format of the .xslx zip file, or use the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-spreadsheetml-document) which like POI would use memory but probably not as much.

Comment: Apache POI provides a low-memory streaming reader for XLSX files - see http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

Comment: @Devbrat Anuragi  Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @RobertBaron no, Just to clarify that my excel file has multiple sheets and each having around 50000 rows

Comment: If you could give more context, about your problem, there might be other ways of reading your Excel file.

Comment: @RobertBaron   should I perform reading data in the background thread

Comment: @RobertBaron Can you tell me how to use Open XML SDK and SpreadSheetML in android Studio

Comment: I am not familiar at all with android Studio and I do not know whether there is an Open XML SDK for android. However, as far as SpreadsheetML is concerned, this is the raw format of an xlsx file. An xlsx file is just a zip file. Change its extension to .zip and you will be able to open it with any zip tool. The files inside are xml files that follow the format documented in the link given in the answer. So, if you have a library that can extract zip files to disk, then all you will have to do is to read XML / text files.